# How can I prove $R^T\ ;R^T$ is transitive if $R$ is transitive.

Tags: relations

If $R$ is transitive relation. 
How can I prove that composition of its transpose is also transitive.

i.e. $R^T\ ;R^T$ is transitive too.

Comment: What is the transposition of a relation?

Comment: @GitGud the matrix of a relation is its adjacency matrix.  That is, the matrix of a relation on $n$ elements is an $n \times n$ matrix whose $a=i,j$ entry is a $1$ if $(x_i,x_j) \in R$ and $0$ otherwise.  The transpose relation is the relation corresponding to the transposed graph.

Comment: More concisely: $xRy \iff y R^Tx$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x R^T y$ and $ y R^T z$. Then $ zRy $ and $ yRx$ by definition of the transpose relation. Since $R$ is transitive, that means that $zRx$. Again, by definition of the transpose relation, $xR^Tz$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!